# Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question? YES

Tags: feature-request

I have been looking at my past questions, and noticed this message:

> Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?

I certainly appreciate the concern and the friendly reminder, but the 52th time I visit the page it starts to get a little bothersome. For that reason I would like to request a way for me to say that: "YES I HAVE CONSIDERED IT AND I DON'T WANT TO".

So, in summation I would like to request that there is a little `yes` button next to the reminder so that when I click it the reminder goes away forever. Please?

Comment: This question should be on the fast track to get its "Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?" flag set.

Comment: But have you *really* considered it? I mean, not just thought about it, but made diagrams and flow charts to ponder the possibilities?

Comment: At the very least could the reminder disappear until there are either changes to answers or new answers offered.

Comment: Do accept few of the answers to your question and that should do the trick. At least that you can do not just for the shake of getting rid of that message but for showing your appreciation for the effort made by answer posters.

Comment: Do you *really* believe that it's possible to not accept an answer or start a bounty?

Comment: @Rahul I thought it's possible to accept only one answer per question.

Comment: @Rahul: To be fair, thesecretmaster _has_ accepted an answer on most of their questions.

Comment: And on the other ones the answers didn't help me, so no accept

Comment: Quite annoying. No, there is no satisfying answer. No, I don't care enough to offer my points for it.